# Crop area jumps after element rotation in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to make a crop functionality like canva.
in crop mode i have a new rect which act as the crop area and user can modifiy as per there requirement.
and once click outside it will take the rect property and apply it on original image.
It work fine until you **rotate** the image and then try this ..
it will jump unexpectedly.

Here is the code for crop function

```
function cropImage() {

  const myFrameElement = getElementById('myFrame');
  var myFrameElementBoundingRect = myFrameElement.getBoundingRect();
  if (selectedObject && selectedObject.type === 'image' && myFrameElement) {

    var selectedObjectBoundingRect = selectedObject.getBoundingRect();

    if ((selectedObject.width * selectedObject.scaleX < myFrameElement.width * myFrameElement.scaleX) || (selectedObject.height * selectedObject.scaleY < myFrameElement.height * myFrameElement.scaleY)) {
      //alert(selectedObject.scaleX + " " + selectedObject.oldScaleX);
    } else {
      //crop
      selectedObject.oldLeft = selectedObject.left;
      selectedObject.oldTop = selectedObject.top;
      selectedObject.oldScaleX = selectedObject.scaleX;
      selectedObject.oldScaleY = selectedObject.scaleY;
      selectedObject.oldWidth = selectedObject.width;
      selectedObject.oldHeight = selectedObject.height;

      selectedObject.cropX = (myFrameElement.left - selectedObject.left) / selectedObject.scaleX;
      selectedObject.cropY = (myFrameElement.top - selectedObject.top) / selectedObject.scaleY;

      selectedObject.width = myFrameElement.width / selectedObject.scaleX;
      selectedObject.height = myFrameElement.height / selectedObject.scaleY;

      selectedObject.left = myFrameElement.left;
      selectedObject.top = myFrameElement.top;
    }
    selectedObject.setCoords();
    canvas.remove(selectedObject.picArea);
    selectedObject.opacity = 1;
    selectedObject.hasRotatingPoint = true;
    selectedObject.picArea = null;
    canvas.discardActiveObject();
    isCrop = false;
  }

}
```

Attached the fiddle please check.
http://jsfiddle.net/mxsgn67r/2/

code refered from Frederic Anand answer